# Add super class to a known class dynamically in Python

Tags: python, oop

Define two classes as follows.

```
class A:
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
```

Now, I want to redefine B as `class B(A, C)`, adding a new parent class `C` dynamically. Here "dynamically" means I input a string 'C', then output modified class B as subclass of A and C, where A may be brought in dynamically.

There may exist two methods, one is to modify the property of B that stores the information of super classes, the other is to redefine B, by which we have to know all of super classes of B.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to get. Include more details in the question. What do you mean by `dinamically`? Where `might exist two methods`? What is `C`?

Comment: Do you want to change the value the *variable* "`B`" or modify the class `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of metaprogramming is usually quite straight-forward in Python. I think you can get away with the following, if you don't mind simply re-defining B, I believe you can essentially re-construct the class dynamically using the `type` constructor and the `mro` method, which gives you the method resolution order:

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     pass
   ...: class B(A):
   ...:     pass
   ...: class C:
   ...:     foo = 42
   ...:
   ...: B = type('B', (*B.mro()[:-1], C), dict(vars(B)))
   ...:
   ...:
```

Note,

```
In [2]: isinstance(B(), A), isinstance(B(), C)
Out[2]: (True, True)

In [3]: B.foo
Out[3]: 42
```

I slice it to avoid `object`, which still behaves implicitly anyway.

```
In [6]: B.mro()
Out[6]: [__main__.B, __main__.B, __main__.A, __main__.C, object]

In [7]: B.mro()[:-1]
Out[7]: [__main__.B, __main__.B, __main__.A, __main__.C]
```

Comment: I considered to use mro. Thank you for your detailed answer. But there exists another problem, If C or some other class which will be added to superclasses of B, is a subclass of A or one of superclasses of B, then I will get an error about mro. Such metaprogramming will be not straight-forward. I will try to define a property such as `is_a` to maintain the superclasses.